# Formula to detect duplicate data in Excel (with a difficult variable!)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to sanitise a mailing list, and am wondering if anyone knows of a formula to find out the following:

I have an excel spreadsheet with two columns A and B, the formula I need to do is: if [value in column B is duplicated] has [blank in column A] AND [data in column A] then show the value of Column B in a new Column C.

Example of data:

```
COL A      |    COL B
11/11/12   |    **name@example.com**
03/09/11   |    different@example.com
           |    **name@example.com**
06/01/12   |    anothername@example.com
```

The formula would detect name@example.com is duplicated & it has a date in column A & further on has no value in column A, and therefore displays: name@example.com in Column C.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: The most complicated part is [value in column B is duplicated]. And I think there is no such formula in Excel. Instead, it is very easy to implement what you need in a form of macros in VBA (Visual Basic for Applications).

Comment: In your example, would it add to column C in row 1 or row 3?

Comment: The only result needed is to show that if it appears more than once, with both a blank column A and a data filled column A - to put it in column C (any row it shows would be fine).

Comment: Thanks for the info Prizoff... I have absolutely NO clue about VBA, so am stumped there before I start!

Comment: its not very hard.. try to record some macros (any), after that, go and edit it - you will see its code in VBA, so  after that you will be able to create any macros you want using some examples from recorded macro and google :)

Comment: but it seems, what bendataclear wrote in his answer is also a good solution :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work (obviously changing the ranges to cover all rows):

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$5,B2)>1,A2=""),B2,"")
```

Comment: This will report all values that occur more than once in column B with at least one occurrence paired with a blank in column A –– _even if **every** occurrence is paired with a blank in column A_.  This violates the “has … AND [data in column A]” part of the question.